# Cannot set breakpoint at malloc()

Tags: c, linux, gcc, gdb, malloc

code sample(foo.c)

```
int main(){
 int *x=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));  // break here
 *x=10;
 free(x);
 return 0;
}
```

I want to break at malloc. Here is what I try:

```
# gcc -g foo.c -o bar
# gdb bar
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x80484cf: file src.c, line 7.
(gdb) r
Breakpoint 1, main () at src.c:7
(gdb) b malloc
Breakpoint 2 at 0x550944
(gdb) c
Program exited normally.
```

My system spec is:

- OS: CentOS 5.5
- gcc: gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)
- gdb: GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.0.1-42.el5)

Please tell me where am I going wrong!!

Comment: find the line of malloc, and inside GDB type break line_number

Comment: I set a break point at the line number with the call to malloc, and it seemed to have worked fine.

Comment: Here (Fedora 20, gcc-4.8.2) it asks me if to enable the breakpoint when the library is loaded, and works fine.

Comment: maybe it was optimized out? try with -O0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cannot reliably reproduce the error, but on Linux you could try breaking at `__libc_malloc` instead of `malloc`.

Answer (score 0):

**Resolved**
Figured it out,
Actually breakpoint was being set in `ld-linux.so` instead of `libc.so`, could resolve it using:

- b __malloc
- b __libc_malloc

Thanks for looking into it!!

Though a new question would be:
how to ask gdb to set breakpoints only in a specific library (I know it can be done for a file)!!